# SVG textpath click radius too high when font-size below 1px

Tags: jquery, css, svg, d3.js, font-size

I have created some **rivers** in D3.js and would like to have them **clickable**. So I created an example [jsfiddle.net/kwoxer/5uc17jwr/19/](http://jsfiddle.net/kwoxer/5uc17jwr/19/).

There you can see that the mouseover of the rivers are overall fine. But the issue is when the font-size is getting below `1px` (e.g. River 9 and River 10) it's not correct anymore. Somehow then the mouseover is buggy and the radius is way too high then.

So below font-size `1px` you can actually move the mouse away from the text and the river text is still highlighted.

I would like to know why it's bugging below `1px` and how I could fix that. Maybe with disabling the outerRadius if there is some?

### Issue examples

1. I would like to have the red and blue marked are with the event. The red one shall highlight the River 11 and the blue one the River 19:

[image]

2. It's nearly the same issue but another case. So here the blue color area is also toggling the highlight when the font-size of the river is too low. I would like to disable that behaviour:

[image]

Comment: I would simply not show text with a font size that small. You certainly won't be able to read anything anyway.

Comment: Well overall that's right but I need it that small, because I have high zooming, so the size is fine and good to read. So the issue is just the highlighting of the text.

Comment: Well the fundamental issue is that the highlighting isn't done on the actual text, but the bounding box. You can see that for river 19 for example. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975021/chrome-textpath-click-and-hover-triggered-outside-of-rendered-text).

Comment: Yeah he has the same issue but I not completely understand how he solved his issue. He said >> I tried with and onclick handler and it works great, disabling the pointer-event for the text enables you to click the path anywhere << but I don't want a onclick event on it. =/

Comment: @Robert: no it's actually bugging in my Firefox, too. It's like Lars said said. It's actually a box. And look on River 19. It's done at the end. That's why River 11 is nearly not clickable. Which Firefox you have?

Comment: I've no idea what you're seeing/experiencing then. Please add more details to your question.

Comment: Added a picture to visualize the main issue.

Comment: It doesn't do that on my Firefox.

Comment: I have Firefox 35.0.1 64bit Windows. I also want to mention that there is a similar misbehaviour in Chrome. There it even more strange. Even on big font-sized texts.

Comment: Well I found out that increasing the scale of the projection is lowering the issues. In Firefox now I would say it's ok. With that increase I can set the font-size to about 1 px instead of 0.2. But the issue with the bounding box in Chrome still exists. =/ The mouseover radius is just to high.

Comment: I'm on a Mac currently so it could be an issue with Direct2D I guess.

Comment: Well I don't have another system except Windows =) But the fiddle is here, so maybe you find some time later on and testing it somewhere else. Otherwhise soon going to a Chrome bug report or whatever. Maybe they have an idea. Big thanks anyway both of you.

Comment: Why don't you just use the river paths for the hit detection instead? That should be much more reliable than using the text labels, those should just have `pointer-events: none` set on them.

Comment: Well in this example here there are river. But in my case I draw just text and want it clickable. River was just an example =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
var projection = d3.geo.equirectangular().translate([80, 0]).scale(220000);
```

I now use

```
var projection = d3.geo.equirectangular().translate([80, 0]).scale(3000000);
```

and to resample the size without manually edit each size by hand I use

```
.attr("font-size", function(d) { return d.properties.size * 11; })
```

With that in Firefox everything is perfect. Just Chrome has still a problem when the text is not horizontal. Then the bounding box is much bigger then the text as you can see from issue picture #2. But I think this is a bug of Chrome.