# SVG letter-spacing also applied to Mozilla Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, text, svg

Is there another alternative to **letter-spacing** in terms of **SVG text**?

This code is **working on Chrome** but **not** on **Firefox**:

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing

As you can see there Firefox is not supporting it right now due to a bug. But I really need letter-spacing in both browser. So is there a good anternative for SVG text?

Btw the same is on **word-spacing**. Working in Chrome perfectly but not on Firefox.

Comment: You could specify a position for every letter using dx or x, or alternatively you could finish the patch in the bug that I started.

Comment: Could you please link to the patch. I cannot find it somehow.

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=371787

Comment: Yeah that is the bug description. Okay was thinking when you say patch you mean workaround. Okay than I got you wrong I think.

Comment: I meant download this patch: https://bug371787.bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=8334130 and fix the issues in it that prevent it from being added to the gecko codebase.

Comment: Thanks but I just see lines of code. No clue how to use it or what else I could learn from this. Would you bother to create a tutorial for this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was that I create the strings with (multiple)whitespaces in QGIS. This is bad way because if you want to give all elements a bigger space it takes a long time.

But it is easy and works on any browser in the same way. So this is the way to go if you have your data in geojson or topojson.

Answer (score 19):

An alternative to `letter-spacing` that does work on Firefox is the `textLength` property.  Perhaps that will suit you as a workaround?

```html
<svg width="10cm" height="3cm" viewBox="0 0 1000 300"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <desc>Example text01 - 'Hello, out there' in blue</desc>

  <text x="250" y="150" 
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="55" fill="blue" >
    Hello, out there
  </text>

  <text x="250" y="200" textLength="600"
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="55" fill="blue" >
    Hello, out there
  </text>

  <!-- Show outline of canvas using 'rect' element -->
  <rect x="1" y="1" width="998" height="298"
        fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Well a good idea, but not sure how I get this to work. I mean I don't have simple text elements. I have **<path ... id=...** that is the line where to write the text to. And then I have **<text ... textpath ....** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28320514/svg-textpath-click-radius-too-high-when-font-size-below-1px there is a jsfiddle. Maybe just edit it there so I better understand what to change. Many thanks.

Comment: So I tested on the textpath .style("textLength", 600) and .attr("textLength", 600), no change. But when I set it on the text .attr("textLength", 600) then I have a change for all text elements. But I don't want it for all =/

Comment: I mean textLength is just one way to do a stretching (http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/SVG_Essentials/Text). And I already tried them all I think. But yeah how can I use it if I paint on a already existing path?

Comment: You never mentioned that you were doing text on a path.  Regardless, `textLength` should still work.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/1off23q9/

Comment: I stumbled upon this because I couldn't get `kerning` or `letter-spacing` to work in the style tag of a svg element.  `textLength` does work but wasn't the solution I was hoping for.  I tried `letter-spacing` directly in the `text` tag's style attribute and it worked.  Not sure why it works this way and not within the svg's style tag.  `<text style="letter-spacing: 2;">...</text>`

Comment: That textLength did not work for me. I had to come up with a combination of dx + letter-spacing, just like Horcrux7 mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the parameter "dx".

```html
<svg width="10cm" height="3cm" viewBox="0 0 1000 300"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">

    <text x="250" y="200" dx="0 20 20 20 20 0 20 20 20 20 20"
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="55" fill="blue" >
         Hello, out there
    </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Actually the only way that worked for me. But although this indeed works for Firefox, it might break layout in other browsers like Chrome, that also evaluate letter-spacing. So you need to combine letter-spacing setting & dx in order to end up with a cross-browser solution.

Answer (score 0):

This was working fine-.  Only had problems in Internetexplorer with 2 lines of text - so Leterspacing in actual Browsers like Chrome (√), Safari (√) and IE (√). Only Firefox ...

```
<svg fill="none" stroke="#838383" stroke-width="1" class="text-line"  width="100%" height="400">
                        <text fill="none" transform="translate(1 1)" textLength="1200"  >
                                <tspan x="0" y="192"><?php  the_field('ani_headline_1st');  ?></tspan>  
                                <tspan x="0" y="342"><?php  the_field('ani_headline_2nd');  ?></tspan>  
                        </text>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox (desktop) now supports the `letter-spacing` property, as of version 73. See browser compatibility at [the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/letter-spacing) and the relevant [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=371787).

Firefox for Android still does not support `letter-spacing`.