# Firefox is ignoring more than one whitespace in SVG text and showing them smaller - compared to Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, text, svg

Concerning this question:[SVG letter-spacing also for the firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28644626/svg-letter-spacing-also-for-the-firefox)

I have a new idea how to solve the issue. So let's say I have as text "**`Sea`**" and "**`S e a`**". In Chrome you really see space between the letters. In Firefox there are nearly none.

I also compared "**`Sea`**" and "**`S     e     a`**" in Chrome fine,a really big space now like here. But in Firefox it is like if there is just one space.

So now the question. How can I **tell Firefox** that the **spaces** have the **same size** like in the Chrome. And how how I tell **Firefox** to **not ignore more than one space**.

I think this would be the best solution for me if this would be even possilble =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Already found it. Setting `white-space: pre;` on **tspan** works as aspected.

The remaining issue is that QGIS where I'm defining my data is not saving multiple whitespace in the presentation. So I just need to find out how that is working.

Edit: here the link to the QGIS question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136311/qgis-multiple-whitespace-in-attributes-are-removed-after-restart

Hopefully someone has an idea there =)

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to set `xml:space` attribute to `preserve` on the text element in question.